# How to auto map data from Request to Model in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to submit my form with many of fields.
As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserts)

```
$flight = new Flight;
$flight->name = $request->name;
$flight->param1 = $request->param1;
$flight->param2 = $request->param2;
...
$flight->param_n = $request->param_n;
$flight->save();
```

Its a bad idea if have too much fields.
I'm looking for any script like:

```
$flight = new Flight;
$flight->save($request->all());
```

But `$request->all()` function got unnecessary fields
What is the best way to do?

Comment: You may use `$request->only('name', 'param1', ...., 'param-n')` instead of `$request->all()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the model `$fillable` array for this so long as your model properties match your request properties exactly.

```
$flight = new Flight();
$data = $request->only($flight->getFillable());
$flight->fill($data)->save();
```

You'll need to specify the fillable fields for any model that you would like to use this behavior for.

*For Laravel 5.4 and lower use `intersect` instead of `only`*

Otherwise you can just whitelist the properties you want from the request

```
$data = $request->only(['param1', 'param2' ...]);
```

Comment: `$fillable` clear all default data from `$attributes`

Comment: @ThanhDao Are those attributes in the request? That shouldn't happen unless the request contains those attributes but the values are blank.

Comment: In model, I set default values in `protected $attributes`, I set whitelist of properties in `protected $fillable`.
=> default values not working when `$request` missing any

Comment: It mean in model, `$this->attributes['title'] = '';`
`$this->fillable = ['title'];`
And the `title` params will be saved as `null`

Comment: This seems like the attributes are actually present in the request and the ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware is causing them to be null, or you're using Laravel 5.4 or lower and `only` is behaving differently https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18695

Comment: Yap, its exactly what happens. I created new a middeware to handle it. Thank for your response

Answer (score 1):

- There are various ways. you can exclude unwanted values as

  $data = $request->except(['_token','_method','etc']);
- The best way would be validated data. viz apply validation on your form inputs on server side.

  $validated_data = $request->validate(['field1'=>'required','field2'=> 'required']);

etc. you can apply desired validations on each field and only validated fields will be in $validated_data variable, and then you can save them.

Comment: Validation always best way with whitelist fields, I think `except()` method is not a good idea. We can not handle what is submitted